# How can I replace pypi requirements.txt modules with links instead?

Tags: python, installation, pip

I have a requirements.txt that I'm pip installing from (pip install -r requirements.txt)

> requirements.txt
>
> ```
> numpy==1.18.2
> pandas==1.1.4
> requests==2.24.0
> ...
> ```

I'm getting a lot of errors with modules giving me this kind of error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement module==x.y.z
ERROR: No matching distribution found for module==x.y.z
```

So I'm debugging and I'd like to try using official download links instead of version numbers. I hope that I'm making sense, because I'm not too familiar with it yet but hopefully I'm being clear enough.

So instead of:

```
numpy==1.18.2
```

I would have:

```
numpy==https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.23.0rc1/
```

Comment: just keep packages name and then install them all, remove vbersions

Comment: I tried that but it still gives me the same 2 errors.